# Angular JS - full page reload if not matching route

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a clean way to do a full page reload if not matching route.

Angular docs page is currently doing a similar thing. When you click on the stuff on the sidebar, it makes an ajax call. But, when clicking on any of the top menu, it does a full page reload.

I guess one possible way is to listen to a route change event, test all the route regexes against the current url and calls the $window.location.reload() if not matching. But I'm hoping for a cleaner way..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use $routeProvider

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        redirectTo:     '/home'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl:    'partials/home',
        controller:     'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:     '/somePage'
    });
}];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: redirectTo would change the URL but will not do a reload

Comment: actually it works if you do redirectTo: function() { window.location.reload() }